# Flatten a object and convert to a list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a class Employee, which contains a list of address

```
class Employee {
    String name;
    Integer age;
    List<String> address;
    Integer salary;
}


Employee object : E1
Employee 
name: Raghu
age : 37
address: [bangalore,chennai]
Salary : 25000
```

I want this to be converted into a List with address flattened as below. For the above object i need a List

```
List<Employee>
Element 1:
name: Raghu
age : 37
address: bangalore
salary: 25000
Element 2:
name: Raghu
age: 37
address: chennai
salary: 25000
```

How to do this with java 8 lambda expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename the `address` variable to `addressList` for better understanding.

You have got an employee with many addresses and want to have multiple (duplicate) employees with just one address?

Check this out:

```
public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return addressList.stream()
            .map(address ->
             new Employee(name, age, Arrays.asList(address), salary))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I assume that you can use a constructor like
`public Employee(String name, int age, List<String> addressList, int salary)`.
Here `name`, `age`, `addressList` and `salary` are instance variables in the `Employee` class.

Comment: Precisely what i wanted. you are awesome.Thanks